# Implicitly unwrapped optional is nil but does not cause runtime exception

Tags: swift

I was under the impression that implicitly unwrapped optional will cause a runtime exception when used and it is nil.  But the following code works without runtime exception, why?

```
var str:String?
println(str!)  // Crashes as expected

var str:String! // Implicitly unwrapped
println(str)    // Does not crash, not what I expect - it prints nil
```

Answer (score 1):

It prints the variable as enum (i.e. optional), because internally an optional is `enum Optional<T>`.
More precisely, I presume it uses the `debugDescription` property, in fact this is what happens:

```
var str:String?
println(str) // Prints "nil"
str.debugDescription // Prints "nil"
```

Comment: It prints nil, which is not what I expect - I thought it would crash.

Answer (score 0):

An implicitly-unwrapped optional is only forcibly unwrapped in a situation which expects a non-optional. `println()` accepts all types, including optionals, and so there is no need to forcibly unwrap it before passing to `println()`. Since it is not unwrapped, it does not crash.